# WebClient taking 43 seconds to download this json string https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Tags: c#, webclient, nancy

12 hours ago (around dinner time here in Texas), it was working just fine at a moment when I hope the latency to be very high because of the high traffic.

Any idea why this could be happening and how to troubleshoot this issue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nancy.Json;

namespace Training.Threading
{
    class TasksDemo
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Post[] posts = await GetPostsAsync();

            foreach(Post post in posts)
                System.Console.WriteLine(post.Title);
        }

        public static Task<Post[]> GetPostsAsync() => Task.Run(() =>
         {
             var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
             JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
             var posts = ser.Deserialize<Post[]>(json);
             return posts;
         });
    }
    public class Post
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, `HttpClient` has async methods on it.

Comment: Also, WebClient is deprecated. In the docu Microsoft recommends to use HttpClient.

Comment: Following the advice fo you all @maccettura and kuri I'm using now HttpClient, but having the same output. Will keep testing the code at different times of the day to eliminate the possibility of high latency due to network congestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code is the issue here. It is more so your ISP or the bandwith available to the server / traffic you are trying to contact.

Some tools that will help you diagnose the issue specifically in windows to spot your issue include

- 'tracert' (trace route)
- 'ping' (ping)

In Windows:

```
ping jasonplaceholder.typicode.com
```

To view latency between "hops"

```
tracert jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
```

this will provide in milliseconds the latency to the server you are trying to reach assuming they respond to ping request ICMP.

Comment: As you pointed out, the problem seems to be related to the server. I will keep testing the code at different times of the day. Thanks for your response, I selected it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice fo @maccettura and @ckuri I'm using now HttpClient, I thought I'd be good to post the code here.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nancy.Json;

namespace Training.Threading
{
    class TasksDemo
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = await GetPostsAsync();
            // System.Console.WriteLine(json);
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var posts = ser.Deserialize<Post[]>(json);

            foreach(Post post in posts)
                System.Console.WriteLine(post.Title);
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetPostsAsync()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                return await client.GetStringAsync("/posts");
            }
        }
    }
    public class Post
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
}
```